# What is an $A^\text{op}$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a difficulty with the notation. Let $A$ be a ring. What is an $A^\text{op}$-module?

Comment: $A^{op}$ is the opposite ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module over the opposite ring of $A$, which is the same ring with multiplication reversed.